# Having trouble understanding peak finding algorithm differences

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

This is a question about 1D peak finding (element is a peak if it's larger than neighbors in array). I'm watching the MIT opencourseware lectures and he talks about the naive solution being starting from index 0 and going to the end.

Then he says a divide and conquer solution is much better. I don't understand how this is the case. Doesn't that make assumptions based on the contents of the array? If it's all just random numbers then what difference does it make?

The lecturer said he wrote a Python script and the naive solution took 13 seconds while the log(N) solution only took .001 seconds. I wrote some C# code and the naive algorithm finds a peak within the first 20 or so elements and takes a millisecond to run. Am I missing something here?

Here's a PDF summary of the lecture: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec01.pdf

Comment: a peak is *no less* than its neighbours.

Answer (score 5):

The thing with the peak is that a peak always exists either in the middle either in the left half either in the right half.

Imagine that you find the middle element is `5` and left of it is `6`. Then is `6` a peak? No if left element of `6` is something bigger, let's say `7`. Then is `7` a peak? No if left element of `7` is something bigger, let's say `8`. You can continue this process until either you find a peak or you reach the leftmost element. In the latter case you get an increasing sequence number of numbers and therefore the leftmost element is a peak.

So if you find that the middle element is smaller than the left neighbor, then you certainly know to look for a peak at the left half. You don't care if there is another peak at the right half, however random the distribution the number is. The same holds if the middle element is smaller to it's right neighbor.

Let's give another example: Assume you are in the middle of the road. You look left and you see a higher point. Then you know one of the two things can happen. Either you'll always go left and find higher and higher points or you find a peak. But you can't go left for ever. If you reach the end of the road then this must be a peak. So it doesn't matter at all what happens at your right. You are confident to find a peak if you travel left.

As far as the running time of your implementation. The naive algorithm will finish fast if it finds a peak near at the beginning. Take a sequence from `1` to `1000000` to test it since then the peak is at the last element.

Comment: I don't even understand how this work with the following example: `[ 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5 ]`. `5` is the peak, but the middle is either `1` or `2`, and you would walk to the left. But the peak value is to the right. What am I missing? Sorry, english is not my native language. Maybe it is just an language issue.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira 4 is also a peak, and you find it

Comment: This algorithm in the link it finds one peak. Doesn't have to be 5. For example 4 is also a peak.

Comment: So the peak element is not the bigger element of the array? Just the one with smaller neighbors? This implies that an array can have lots of peaks, right? And the algorithm mission is to find only a single one?

Comment: Yeap you nailed it!! :p

Comment: Oh! How dumb. Now it makes perfect sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: But does he make a note anywhere of any logic or pattern in the array? If it's just random numbers wouldn't the naive algorithm be the same? I understand the logic assuming patterns but he doesn't really explicitly state the layout of the array..

Comment: great answer, maybe for completeness mention the case when they are equal (left, mid and right), which is also considered a peak.  So in [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 6] is it not necessary to find 6.

Comment: The naive algorithm checks every element. The algorithm in the lecture guesses correctly in which half to look. It does it with success because whatever pattern the data have, we can find a peak in the left or the right half. And we can know the direction by checking what happens with the middle element and it's neighbors.

Comment: @rpattiso Paradocixally the same argument applies even in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Divide an conquer is better because is it has an `O(log n)` time complexity in the worst case. This asymptotic upper bound does not depend on the content of the array. A naive algorithm has an `O(n)` time complexity. It can make a huge difference on large arrays.
2. The part about your benchmark is very unclear. What kind of tests did you run? How did you measure the execution time? The fact that an implementation of a naive algorithm found a peak in one particular array quickly does not mean that it is efficient in general.

Comment: I measured the execution time with a C# stopwatch. I filled an array of 10,000,000 elements with random integers ranging from 0 to 10,000,000. If it's all random then how does divide and conquer help at all I don't understand.